# How to define relations with cakePHP?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-model

I've read about convections and I have my application/database straight.

I've read too about $hasOne, $hasMany, $belongsTo, etc

But, I'm facing a problem/issue that I can't solve for my self.

My models: Car, Event, Refuel, Repair 
My controller: CarsController

My relations:

```
class Car extends AppModel {
    public $BelongsTo = array('User');
    public $hasMany = array('Event');
}
```

.

```
class Event extends AppModel {
    public $BelongsTo = array('Car');
    public $hasOne = array('Refuel');
}
```

.

```
class Refuel extends AppModel {
    public $BelongsTo = array('Event');
}
```

**Output of find()** excecuted from CarsController

```
array(
    'Car' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'user_id' => '1',
        'make' => 'Make',
        'model' => 'Model',
    ),
    'Event' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'car_id' => '1',
            'dateEvent' => '20-10-2014',
            'description' => '1'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'car_id' => '1',
            'dateEvent' => '20-10-2014',
            'description' => '2'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'car_id' => '1',
            'dateEvent' => '20-10-2014',
            'description' => '3'
        )
    )
)
```

**You need to know this:** 

Car belongs to a User. User may have many cars 
Car has many events. An event just have one car. 
To each Event should be associated one refuel or one repair. A refuel or repair cant have more than one event associated.

**Tables:**

users: id 
cars: id, user_id 
events: id, car_id 
refuels: id, event_id (unique) 
repairs: id, event_id (unique)

1. Have I defined well the relations ?
2. How to express it in cakePHP, special events-refuels and events-repairs?

Comment: Can you explain the problem or question you have?  You've provided a lot of good data, but - not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found that array('recursive' => 2) solve the problem!

But what is this and why ?

Comment: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive**, **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html**

Comment: Recursive 2 is bad.  Don't use it.  Use Containable instead.  Good news though, if setting recursive to 2 gets you the data you want, that means your associations are likely correct.

Answer (score 0):

You missed

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array('Car');
}
```